# How do you change the default programming language visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I installed Visual Studio 2013 again after I got a new PC, but now when I create a new file it creates it as an VB file instead of c#.

I changed the default programming language in web.config like shown here:

[image]

I tried reloading the project but it still does not work.

The web project is placed on a local ftp server.

Comment: When you make a new project, under _Templates_ you should see a node for _Visual Basic_ and one for _Visual C#_ with the different types of projects listed under the language. I believe VS remembers which one you used last.

Comment: And it may have defaulted to VB when you created the project, and you didn't realize it.  (At least that's happened to me before).  Once, I explicitly created a C# project, it remembered that choice for other, future projects, as @Jasen says.

Comment: Let me try and explain: The project was created by doing exactly that. But now that I reinstalled my computer and opened it with "Open Website", the  default language seems to be VB.net. Never had this problem with Visual Studio 2010 when opening a website project from ftp.

Comment: Did you add the new file through the top menu _FILE > New File_? Or did you right-click in the _Solution Explorer_? Do you see the Visual C# templates installed when you add new items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu that shows up when you right click on a folder > "Add" shows a list of the options available for that folder ex. if you are in App_code it shows "Class". It seems it doesn't change the first suggestion to C# class even tho you change the programming language. So to fix that you go into the same menu and pick "Add New item..." and select C# Class file ...close it. Now if you try and create a file again it still says "Class" in the Add menu, but when you select it now, it creates it as an C#.

Sovled the problem for me. Thanks to all of you leading me to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a new project, under *Templates* you should see a node for *Visual Basic* and one for *Visual C#* with the different types of projects listed under the language. I believe VS remembers which one you used last.

[image: VS2013 New Project]